# Selenium findElements() / findElement(by class) returns null

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea

When I try to search for an element or elements with the webDriver, it returns nothing.
OS: Ubuntu 14.04, FrameWork: Intellij Idea, Language: Java.

I have these statements:

```
WebDriver myWebDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
String myClass = "hid";
```

and go to:

```
myWebDriver.navigate().to("https://www.youtube.com/");
```

All of that works. But when I declare:

```
 private List <WebElement> myElements = new ArrayList<WebElement>();
```

and then access myElements as such:

```
myElements = myWebDriver.findElements(By.className(myClass));
```

myElements is null as findElements seems to fail, as well as findElement(webElement) (with the latter, I changed the List to a regular WebElement). This has worked previously.

and Here all the code:

```
package com.search.mywork;
        import org.junit.Test;
        import org.openqa.selenium.*;
        import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
        import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.List;
        import java.util.Set;
        /**
         * Created by aby on 5/27/14.
         */

        public class searchWork {
            private long time = 5000;
            private String experience = "1-2 שנים";

            private WebDriver myWebDriver ;
            private WebElement mywebelement ;

            private List <WebElement> jobList = new  ArrayList<WebElement>();
            private List <WebElement> basketList = new  ArrayList<WebElement>();
            private List <WebElement> experienceList = new  ArrayList<WebElement>();
            private List <WebElement> myElements = new  ArrayList<WebElement>();

            private int i=0;
            private int t=0;

            String myClass=  "hid" ;

            private String myLastJobClicked = null;
            private String myLastJobClickedSearch = null;

            private void logIn(){
                //Create Driver and log in
                WebDriver myWebDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
        //        myWebDriver.navigate().to(" http://www.drushim.co.il/Enter.aspx");
        //        myWebDriver.findElement(By.id("MainContent_Login_EmailText")).sendKeys("");
        //        myWebDriver.findElement(By.id("MainContent_Login_PasswordText")).sendKeys("");
        //        myWebDriver.findElement(By.id("MainContent_SubmitLogin")).click();
        //        myWebDriver.navigate().to("http://www.drushim.co.il/jobs/subcat/68/?area=1");
                myWebDriver.navigate().to("https://www.youtube.com/");

            }

            private void searchForWeb(){
                //Go to web Search
                myWebDriver.navigate().to("http://www.drushim.co.il/jobs/subcat/68/?area=1");

                //Wait if needed

                synchronized (myWebDriver){
                    try {
                        myWebDriver.wait(time);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } //Func not used

            private Boolean chkExperienceIsOk(String experienceFromWeb){
                //Check if Experience is ok
        //        if(experience == myWebDriver.findElement(By.className("additionalText")).getText()){
        //            myWebDriver.findElement(By.className("addToBaseketLink")).click();
        //        }
                return experience == experienceFromWeb ? true : false;
            }

            private void findelements(){
                try {
                    //jobList = myWebDriver.findElements(By.className("yt-dialog-loading"));
                    //jobList = myWebDriver.findElements(By.className("yt-dialog-loading"));
                    //mywebelement = myWebDriver.findElement(By.className("yt-dialog-loading"));
                    myElements = myWebDriver.findElements(By.className(myClass));
                    int i =0;
                    //basketList = myWebDriver.findElements(By.className("addToBaseketLink"));
                    //experienceList =  myWebDriver.findElements(By.className("additionalText"));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            private void clickOnModaa(){

                for (WebElement jobElement : jobList){
                    jobElement.click();
                    for (WebElement basketElement : basketList){
                        for (WebElement experienceElement :experienceList)
                        if (chkExperienceIsOk(experienceElement.getText())){
                            basketElement.click();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            private void closeWebDriver(){
                myWebDriver.close();
            }

            @Test
            public void search (){

                logIn();
                //searchForWeb();
                findelements();


                }//end sear fucn

            }//end class
```

Comment: It is nothing to say without HTML.

Comment: you can see i go to("https://www.youtube.com/"); 
there is the html..

Comment: Everything seems to be ok. Could you post all your code?. I can see that myElements is a field so, where do you assign values and use them?

Comment: I wanted post all my code, but when i try to copy/paste, it's not paste all the code like code.. i was clear?
I try, but...

Comment: Its possible to upload the files?

Comment: i Debug it for this reason i saw that myElements still be NULL

Comment: What Selenium & Firefox versions are you running?

Comment: FF: 29.0
Selenium: 2.41.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your problem:

```
private void logIn(){
     //Create Driver and log in

    // myWebDriver is a Class field already
    // Remove WebDriver declaracion

    this.myWebDriver = new FirefoxDriver();

    myWebDriver.navigate().to("https://www.youtube.com/");
}
```

You are creating a new `WebDriver`, so when you use it at `findElements` function it's not properly initialized.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Remove WebDriver myWebDriver = new FirefoxDriver();, just leave myWebDriver = new FirefoxDriver();

Comment: haaa.. is ok! got it!

Comment: @AbyW I updated the answer using "this" to be more specific. Hope you understand now. :)